# How to make git diff-index work in bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying to set up a workflow with pipelines in which all new images are first compressed, using tinypng API, and then sent out to AWS S3. AWS upload works, however I'm having trouble with the first part.

My current setup is:

- index.js file, in which I use tinify npm package (tinypng's official one); it takes external arguments: `const images = process.argv;`
- package.json, where I have a script with `diff` checking for new image files:

```
  "scripts": {
    "compress": "LIST=`git diff-index --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD | grep -E '(.*)\\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG)' | grep -v json`; if [ \"$LIST\" ]; then node index.js $LIST; fi"
  },
```

- and then, in my `bitbucket-pipelines.yml`, in one of the steps, I simply use

```
script:
  - yarn
  - yarn compress
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work as expected. `yarn` works, and `yarn compress` is executed, however it returns almost immediately, without doing any of the actual compression work:

```
+ yarn compress
yarn run v1.13.0
$ LIST=`git diff-index --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD | grep -E '(.*)\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG)' | grep -v json`; if [ "$LIST" ]; then node index.js $LIST; fi
Done in 0.19s.
```

Why can it be? Locally, this setup (obciously without pipes) works, and when I call `yarn compress` from the command line, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you are focusing on `git diff-index`, as that may have nothing to do with the actual problem.  Let's take a look though.

[The `git diff-index` command](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index):

> Compares the content and mode of the blobs found in a tree object with
> the corresponding tracked files in the working tree, or with the
> corresponding paths in the index.

This is full of [jargon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jargon), but the jargon is important:

- *Blobs* are Git's internal representation of file content.  The *mode* part here is mostly irrelevant to your task, but the modes are found in the *tree* objects when using a commit, or in the *index* when using the index.  They're part of the result of calling [`lstat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/lstat) on files in the working tree.
- *Tree object* refers to the sub-part of a commit that stores the blob and mode values.  This is almost of tautological or redundant at this point, except that instead of `HEAD`, you could specify a particular tree object, perhaps even a sub-tree within a commit.  Since you use `HEAD`, the tree you're comparing is that of the *current commit*, in this Git repository.
- A *tracked file* is simply a file that exists in Git's index.  Since `git diff-index` is—perhaps—going to compare a committed file to one that is in Git's index, the file would have to *be* in Git's index for this case.  If you choose to compare to a file in the working tree instead, the file *still* has to be in Git's index, even though there's no obvious reason for that any more; this sentence makes it clear that this is the case (even though it's not clear *why*).
- The *working tree* is where you have some commit checked out.  If a repository is "bare", it has no working tree.

The `--cached` argument is required to get `git diff-index` to compare a commit's tree (e.g., `HEAD`) vs an index, so you're comparing `HEAD` to a checked-out commit's working tree.

This means your Bitbucket pipeline must be checking out a commit.  Consulting the [Atlassian documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/configure-bitbucket-pipelinesyml/), it seems that this is the case: a pipeline spins up a virtual machine (probably a Docker image), and in that image, installs some software, then uses `git clone` with a default `--depth 50` to make a shallow clone.  (I have not examined this documentation closely, just skimmed over it a few times looking for specifics about how it uses Git.)

After that, it seems to run the various `step` instructions.  You seem to expect some of them to modify and/or delete some files from the working tree.  You then use:

> ```
> git diff-index --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD
> ```

With the `diff-filter` setting of lowercase `d`, this would remove from the output any files with status `D`, leaving you with a list of tracked files where the working tree copy differs from that in the `HEAD` commit.

I'm quite sure this still works in the Bitbucket repository.  Yet you describe it this way:

> ... where I have a script with diff checking for new image files:

This is not checking for *new* files.  This is checking for *modified but not deleted* files in the working tree, as compared to the same files as archived in the `HEAD` commit.

The output from this Git command is run through some further filtering:

> ```
> | grep -E '(.*)\\.(jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG)' | grep -v json
> ```

The `(.*)` part is not necessary; the rest of the first `grep` argument makes sure that each line contains one of the listed sequences (`.jpg`, `.JPG`, etc).  If the line contains that anywhere—e.g., if the name of a file is `foo.JPG.bar`—it is passed through.  If that contains `json`, we drop it, otherwise we keep it.

The final result of all of this goes into the variable named `LIST`:

> ```
> LIST=...
> ```

after which we test this with the `[` aka [test](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) program:

> ```
> if [ \"$LIST\" ]; then node index.js $LIST; fi
> ```

So, if any files are modified (but not deleted) in the working tree, we'll run `node index.js` on those files.

What, precisely, are you expecting will modify some set of tracked files here?  That would be the place to concentrate.